# winsock connect function returns Bad file descriptor

Tags: sockets, file-descriptor

I am new to Windows socket programming.
I am trying to write a simple client program and everytime I run it with `127.0.0.1` the connect function keeps returning `bad file descriptor`, for some reason.

Can someone please have a look and tell me why?
I've been trying for ages.

```
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
    exit(1);
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
{

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1) {
        perror("client: socket");
        continue;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd , p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen,0) == -1) {
        printf("hello\n");
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: connect");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
    return 2;
```

Comment: You must call `perror()` *before* calling anything else that could corrupt it. Probably you're really getting ECONNREFUSED or similar. Fix and amend.

Comment: thanks for answering man...but i put perror() before clsoe(sockfd) and it is now showing no error.  but it still wouldnt connect .....this is so frustrating......:(

Comment: Showing *what* error? And did you put it before the `printf()`?

Comment: yeah man i tried  it is showing

Comment: client : connect : no error

Comment: Let's get this straight. You called `connect()`; it returned -1; you *immediately* called `perror()`, without doing anything in between; and it printed 'no error'? I don't believe it.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong parameter values to `socket()`.  You need to pass the socket parameters that `getaddrinfo()` gives you.  You are using `AF_UNSPEC` when calling `getaddrinfo()`, so it can return both IPv4 and IPv6 information, but you are hard-coding your `socket()` call to create only IPv4 sockets, so `connect()` will fail if you pass an IPv6 address to an IPv4 socket.

Also, you are checking the result of `socket()` for the wrong error value.  Unlike other platforms, `socket()` on Windows returns a `SOCKET` handle rather than an `int` file descriptor.  You need to use a `SOCKET` variable instead of an `int` variable, and compare the socket to `INVALID_SOCKET` instead of `-1`.

Also, you have to use `closesocket()` instead of `close()` to close a `SOCKET` handle.  And don't forget to free the list that `getaddrinfo()` returns.

```
SOCKET sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
//...

for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
{
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        perror("client: socket");
        continue;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen, 0) == -1) {
        perror("client: connect");
        closesocket(sockfd);
        sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
    return 2;
}
```